# Cant save multiple user input from textarea in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have retrieve data from lvl2itquepaper and display it with textarea and save the user input to another table call lvl2itresult but when I press save, it save the last user input only. 
For example, got 2 question with 2 text area, 1st text area are 'A' and 2nd text area are 'B', it save both user input as 'B'

```
             <?php
               include('../dbconnect.php');
              session_start();
             ?>



                <!DOCTYPE html>
           <html>

              <head>
                   <title>Online Examination System</title>
              </head>
            <body>


    <div id="container">
    <h1>Level 2 IT Question Paper</h1>
    <h2>Please read the question carefully and answer it confidently. Good Luck All!</h2>


        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
        {
            $sql="SELECT * from lvl1itquepaper";
        $run_que = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        $check_que = mysqli_num_rows($run_que);

            while ($row=$run_que->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $questionno = $row['questionno'];
                $question = $row['question'];
                $student_ans = $_POST['studentans'];


                $sql="insert into lvl2itresult (questionno, question, studentans, username) values ('.$questionno.', '$question', '$student_ans', '".$_SESSION['login_user']."')";

                $submit = $mysqli->query($sql);


            }            
        }
        ?>




        <form method= "post">
    <?php
        echo "Welcome, ";
        $sql="SELECT * from lvl2itstudent WHERE username= '".$_SESSION['login_user']."'";
        $find_student = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        $check_student = mysqli_num_rows($find_student);
            if ($check_student>0){
                while($row = $find_student->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo $row['username'];
                }
            }
        echo "<br><br><br><br>";

        $sql="SELECT * from lvl2itquepaper";
        $run_que = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        $check_que = mysqli_num_rows($run_que);

        if($check_que>0){
            while ($row=$run_que->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $questionno = $row['questionno'];
                $question = $row['question'];
                echo "".$questionno. "." .$question."<br>";
                echo "<textarea name='studentans' rows='5' cols='50'></textarea><br><br>";



            }
        }

             else {
            echo "there is no data in database";
        }
            ?>
            <input type="submit" value = "Submit" name= "Submit" style= "width:60px; height:30px";>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: hi. Because <textarea name='studentans' --> name is the same. it will override. so just do something <textarea name='studentans<?php=$i++?>' and you will be ok

Comment: hi, thank for reply but after that it show Undefined index: studentans in C:\xampp\htdocs\OnlineExaminationSystem\admin\lvl2itque.php on line 33.  $student_ans = $_POST['studentans'];

Comment: ok see the following answer from @Zeke. <textarea name='studentans[]'.... and in a php side .....$student_ans = $_POST['studentans'][$i];

Comment: thank you for your reply. i finally solve my issues and thank you again

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @sim don't forget to mark the answer as correct to close the topic and let other people find the solution quicker! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy, but hard to explain in a few words. What's pretty much going on is that only one parameter is being sent in the POST data since no *array* has been set; furthermore PHP is not treating the information as arrays either, so there's only one value to be interpreted. In any case, if the data was sent correctly, PHP would identify the POST value as an array of 2 dimensions, outputting a SQL error for not being able to parse the data as a string.

To solve this, first change your `<textarea>` tag as follows:

```
<textarea name='studentans[]' rows='5' cols='50'></textarea>
```

The brackets will tell HTML that there will be many elements with the name `studentans`.

Now breaking into your insert logic, you need to treat the arrays getting the values using indexes. Usually these will start on 0, so we will work with that:

```
$i = 0; // $i stands for index.
while ($row=$run_que->fetch_assoc()){
    $questionno = $row['questionno'];
    $question = $row['question'];
    $student_ans = $_POST['studentans'][$i]; // this is where the magic happens

    $sql="insert into lvl2itresult (questionno, question, studentans, username) values ('$questionno', '$question', '$student_ans', '".$_SESSION['login_user']."')";
    // please also notice I deleted 2 concatenating dots near "values ('$questionno',"
    $submit = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $i++; // increment by 1 so we can access the next value on the next loop
}
```

And that should do it. I hope I didn't forget any detail.

Comment: **Do not** forget to initialize `$i` before entering the `while-loop` nor incrementing the `$i` value before its end. That is essential.

Comment: thank you so much and really appreciate that u solve my issues now

Comment: No problem at all, that's what we're all here for. Good luck with your project and don't forget to mark the answer as correct so that more people can benefit from it!